# Shell script to find and replace a string

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

Hello I have a colleague of mine who is a procedural code developer and has same smtp server name sitting in 120 different files, now I have to change them to something else. But doing that one by one would be impossible. I am using "grep" to recursively search for a string in all the files sitting in that directory. But I am not sure if grep can edit the file and replace it with the new string.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Anyway, you should be looking at a combination of `find` and `sed`.

Possibly something like:

```
find . -iname "<filepattern>" -exec sed -e "s/<regex to look for>/<replacement>/g" -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sed`.

```
grep -rl smtp1.example.com . | xargs sed -i 's/smtp1.example.com/smtp2.example.com/g'
```

which means find all files containing `smtp1.example.com`; output their names; pass each filename to the `sed` command, which does a search-and-replace on each file.

`grep` will only list files that actually contain the text; this minimises the number of files for which `sed` is invoked. (Using `find -type f` results in `sed` being invoked on any file.)

Answer (score 1):

```
find /directory -type f -exec sed -i 's/oldname/newname/g' {} +
```

Searches recursively through `/directory` and uses `sed` to do a search and replace. The `{}` is replaced by the file names that are found.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

`find /path/to/start/from/ -type f | xargs perl -pi -e 's/textToFind/TextToReplace/g'`